# How would i find the connector of minimum wieght between two patches which have multiple connectors?

Tags: netlogo

It is important that the minimum connectors are found between two origin and destination pairs. This is not the basis for a full blown model but rather a process that must take place in order for my model to run (my model is a road network in which road users initially follow the optimum route until the traffic density on a chosen route causes an individual vehicle to change the route that is being taken to minimise the time of travel between an origin and a destination).

The problem I have is that I am not sure how to go about finding the minimum connector while the connector patches are being placed down between two origin and destination patches during the time period when the network is being built.

[image]
Here is an example of a network that has been built. The orange square is where the cars will be destroyed and the blue square is where the cars are created and will then begin to flow around the network along the roads (dark grey). What I want to be able to do is to find the minimum road distance between the blue and orange squares as the network is being drawn out so that the cars can flow along the path of minimum weight between the blue and orange patch to replicate how users might get from a to b while using a road network. How could I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean when you talk about connecting patches, but if you use turtles, you can use NetLogo's new network extension: https://github.com/NetLogo/Network-Extension


Using the ```nw:link-path-to```, you can return a list of links connecting the calling turtle with the provided parameter turtle. If you use ```length``` on that, it will tell you how many there are. You can use the 'weighted' ```path-to``` reporters to find weighted paths, i.e. taking into account 'congestion' on the links in your model.

If this doesn't work for your purpose, please do clarify.

Comment: I have added an image to try demonstrate what I want to achieve.